# Seeking title of 1970s science fiction novella about an agricultural society where job is to build a soul

Tags: story-identification

I thought the title was "Be Aware" but apparently not. All I have is that men are territorial but solitary and women are called Scouts. Written in the daughter's voice (there's a son and young daughter).

Comment: Nice question, can I suggest you look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can remember any details, especially what makes it a science fiction novella

Answer (score 3):

*Solitude* by Ursula K. Le Guin

The narrator, her mother and brother go to live on the planet Eleven-Soro as the mother is Observer.

> “Solitude” is a meditative story about a world in which conviviality
>   is deeply distrusted. Women live alone in their own houses in an
>   “auntring” or village, where they make baskets and do gardening, and
>   practice the non-verbal art of “being aware.” Only the children go
>   from house to house, learning lore. When girls come of age they form
>   part of an auntring, but boys must go off to join adolescent packs and
>   scratch a living in the wilderness. They fight it out, and those who
>   survive become breeding males, living shyly in hermit huts, guarding
>   the auntrings from a distance, and being visited by the women, who
>   “scout” for purposes of mating.

http://www.nybooks.com/articles/2002/09/26/the-queen-of-quinkdom/

> I settled down. Some of my time went to gathering and gardening and
>   mending and all the dull, repetitive actions of primitive life, and
>   some went to singing and thinking the songs and stories I had learned
>   here at home and while scouting, and the things I had learned on the
>   ship, also. Soon enough I found why women are glad to have children
>   come to listen to them, for songs and stories are meant to be heard,
>   listened to. "Listen!" I would say to the children ... When they left,
>   I went on in silence. Sometimes I joined the singing circle to give
>   what I had learned travelling to the older girls. And that was all I
>   did; except that I worked, always, to be aware of all I did.
>
> By solitude the soul escapes from doing or suffering magic; it escapes
>   from dullness, from boredom, by being aware. Nothing is boring if you
>   are aware of it. It may be irritating, but it is not boring. If it is
>   pleasant the pleasure will not fail so long as you are aware of it.
>   Being aware is the hardest work the soul can do, I think.